# awk to output two files based on match or no match

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am trying to print out the lines that match have the string `FP` or `RFP` `$2` in the tab-delimited input.  If a match is found in `$2` then in `result` only the lines of `file` that do not have those keywords in them are printed. At the same time another file `removed` is printed that has those lines that did have those keywords in them.  The `awk` has a syntax error in it when I try to print two files, if I only print one the `awk` runs.  Thank you :).

**input**

```
12      aaa
123 FP  bbb
11      ccc
10  RFP ddd
```

**result**

```
12      aaa
11      ccc
```

**removed**

```
123 FP  bbb
10  RFP ddd
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{d["FP"];d["RFP"]}!($2 in d) {print > "removed"}; else {print > "result"}' file
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{d["FP"];d["RFP"]}!($2 in d) {print > "removed"}; else {print > "result"}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                          ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`else` goes with `if`. Your script didn't have an `if`, just an `else`, hence the syntax error. All you need is:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print > ($2 ~ /^R?FP$/ ? "removed" : "result")}' file
```

or if you prefer the array approach you are trying to use:

```
awk -F'\t' '
    BEGIN{ split("FP RFP",t,/ /); for (i in t) d[t[i]] }
    { print > ($2 in d ? "removed" : "result") }
' file
```

Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn awk syntax and semantics.

Btw when writing if/else code like you show in your question:

```
if ( !($2 in d) ) removed; else result
```

THINK about the fact you're using negative (`!`) logic which makes your code harder to understand right away AND opens you up to potential double negatives. Always try to express every condition in a positive way, in this case that'd be:

```
if ($2 in d) result; else removed
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanations... I just got `Effective Awk Programming` and have started to read it :)